# Visio shapes distort on changing scale

Tags: scale, visio

I am trying to change Visio Measurement units and the scale for my existing wire frames. Doing so distorts any use of stencils that have have been designed at a different scale and unit. Any way I can sync up the two?

Answer (score 0):

How are you changing the unit/scale? 
You should be able to do it in Page Setup without any distortion. When shapes of a different scale are added to a drawing their size will adjust to match the scale of the page.